# Z-index object center alignment

Tags: html, css, z-index, center

```
#sidebar input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    margin-left: 13px; 
    height: 22px;
    width: 129px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background-color: #d9e4ea;
    font-size: 13px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

input[type=submit] {
    margin: 0;
    width: 101px;
    height: 16px;
    background: url(images/img06.png) no-repeat left top;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

I have two input types and I want the submit button to be behind the text input and to be centered on the y axis respectively to the first object (text input). I can't manage to center it correctly. I can do it by adjusting margins but then I get different result in every browser and so it's not exactly in the center.

http://jsfiddle.net/7hbq5/10/

Comment: That's some horrible HTML structure you have there. You have `ul` with no `li` children...that's invalid on it's face.

Comment: I am not 100% sure what's being asked, are you trying to put the submit behind the name input or password input? and then align it based on which? name?

Comment: Paulie_D - It's only in this example, I deleted the other parts of the html, but in general it's fine.
Huangism - No, I'm trying to put the submit button (the orange one) behind the password input and center the button on y axis so that it would be in the center of the text input.

Comment: **" I'm trying to put the submit button (the orange one) behind the password"** - WHY? What does this give you?

Comment: "behind the password input" It's a design aspect. The button style that I'm using is a bit odd to correctly align to the input because it's not a regular shape. That's why I'm putting it behind the input and so it stick out just a bit and looks good. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To vertically center an absolutely positioned element with known height inside it's parent container is an easy task and guaranteed to work cross browser:

```
.centeredVertically {
 position: absolute; 
 height: 16px;
 top: 50%; /* push down by 50% of the height of the container */
 margin-top: -8px; /* bring it back up by half of it's height */
}
```

Make sure you add `position: relative` to your form so that it becomes the context for your submit button. See the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7hbq5/11/

Comment: And what if my form is bigger and has more elements in it? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7hbq5/ I see how I can do it by putting it in a container how You did. Should I just adjust the percentage until I get the right look?

Comment: Just make sure that the parent element of the input your are aligning with is the same height of the input. The easiest way is to just wrap your `input` and `submit` elements in a single container that has `position: relative`. Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/7hbq5/15/ As a side note, that is invalid HTML that you have posted in that fiddle. a `ul` element can only have `li` elements as immediate children, not any other type of element or node (including a text node).

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank You! :) Oh and the `ul` is fine, it has a few `li` elements in there, I just deleted them for this example. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want align the divs on y axis. If you have width of the both input boxes predetermined, just use position absolute for both and give left and top on both the divs.

See the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7hbq5/12/

```
input[type=password] {
    height: 22px;
    width: 129px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    font-size: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top:0;
    left:0;    
}

input[type=submit] {
    position: absolute;
    left:14px;
    top:3px;
    width: 101px;
    height: 16px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 7px; 
    border-radius: 7px;  
    background-color: #ff672a;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

- put position relative on the parent div to start a new BFC. (the children are absolute wrt the div)

Comment: Block formatting context https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

Comment: A `BFC` is not important. A positioning context is what's important, and what is created when you put `position: relative` (or absolute, or fixed) on an element.

Comment: My bad! I thought positioning context was also a BFC. Intent was the element should be absolutely positioned wrt the parent hence giving position relative there is necessary.